# Get the 'dropped' div from the onDrop callback using React

Tags: javascript, events, draggable, reactjs

The onDrop event is being triggered in a React component but since it is a synthetic event, the parameters for the event only seem to include the destination of the dropped div, not the dropped div itself. I need to reference the div that was dropped. All that is returned through the parameters is this object: `SyntheticDragEvent {dispatchConfig: Object, dispatchMarker: ".0.0", nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "drop", target: div.col-sm-3.drop-area…}` 
Does anyone know of a way to retrieve the source rather than just the target?

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing the code, but what you can do is setTransferData on dragStart, and you can get the transfer data from the native event. Give it a proper name like, setData('myObject', dataGoesHere); and you can call getData on the transferData on the other side. Also, make sure that you return false in your droppable div for the dragenter event so that it is eligible for dropping items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the native event from any `SyntheticEvent` with the `nativeEvent` property.  From there you should be able to access anything you could from the normal event.  So for example using `SyntheticEvent.nativeEvent` gives you access to `.dataTransfer` `.currentTarget` `.target` `.relatedTarget` and etc.  `SyntheticEvent.nativeEvent.target` being the one you're looking for I think.